# Mac + system path : How can we overcome/centralize local system path while working in team?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation

We are team for 4 members. We are able to execute all automation script on our own machine/computer. When we commit on repository we purposefully do not commit our local path and if anyone commit by mistake all other needs to remove that path of other's system, other wise test script will fail.

Do you know how to overcome this problem? How can we keep common path for everyone?

Q - How can we overcome/centralize local system path while working in team?

Comment: set up a server and execute your test scripts on this server only?

Comment: yeah - Its a plan